# What does the argument "Fitted" accept within "transform"?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

Quick coding question that I'm not finding the answer to readily - have searched R help and online a fair bit.

I'm following along [a post regarding prediction vs. confidence intervals](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/01/glm-prediction-intervals-i).

There is a line of code as shown below:

```
pd <- transform(pd, Fitted = ilink(fit), Upper = ilink(fit + (2 * se.fit)),
                Lower = ilink(fit - (2 * se.fit)))
```

I'm a bit lost as to what `fit` and the argument `Fitted` are doing. I have the sense they are being used to predict model outputs, but I can't see `fit` defined anywhere in the code shown in the post.

Comment: Fitted isn’t an argument. It’s the name of the new column being created. Typically other symbols would be column names present in the object passed to transform, in this case pd.

Answer (score 4):

- `Fitted` is the name of a new variable to be created within the `pd` data frame (so are `Upper` and `Lower`)
- `fit` is a variable that already exists within the `pd` data frame (so is `se.fit`)

Without looking at the blog post, I'm pretty sure that `pd` was generated from `predict(., se.fit=TRUE)`: from `?predict.lm`,

> If ‘se.fit’ is ‘TRUE’, a list with the following components is
>        returned:
>
> fit: vector or matrix as above
>
> se.fit: standard error of predicted means
>
> residual.scale: residual standard deviations
>
> df: degrees of freedom for residual

If you're working with GLMs you should look at `?predict.glm()` which gives similar (but not identical) answers.  As it says there

> type: the type of prediction required.  The default **[i.e. type="link"]** is on the scale
>   of the linear predictors; the alternative ‘"response"’ is on
>             the scale of the response variable.

If you use `type="link"` for a binomial model with logit link you'll get responses on the log-odds (logit) scale, which aren't restricted to (0,1).

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is helpful - two quick follow up questions: (1) I seem to only have these variables returned if I use `type=link` - what is `link`? (2) What exactly does `fit` represent? I'm working with a logistic model and I was expecting values of [0-1], but it seems `fit` has values above 1